# yearpicker date change event

Tags: jquery, date

I want to detect the event when a user select a year, I am using [yearpicker](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Year-Picker-Text-Input.html)

html:

```
<input type="text" class="yearpicker form-control" value="2020" id="y_picker" readonly/>
```

I tried:

```
$("#y_picker").change(function () {
    alert('hhh');
});
```

but the event doesn't fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its
>   value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for
>   INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.

taken from the [W3C HTML Events docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents).

The input's value is changed programmatically so the `onchange` event never happens. It needs to be triggered programmatically inside of the yearpicker plugin. To do so, open *yearpicker.js*, search for the method `setValue` (line 399) and add the last line of the following code:

```
  if (this.isInput) {
    $this.val(value);
  } else {
    $this.html(value);
  }
  // trigger the change event:
  $this.trigger("change");
```

Comment: You are welcome :-). I forked the repository and fixed the issue which can be found [here](https://github.com/Moonbird-IT/YearPicker/blob/master/yearpicker.js)